# What is the magic that makes probability theory "work"?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, borel-sets

This is a bit of an abstract math question I'm sure someone can shed light on.

I am doing some dense probability calculations. One thing that just keeps amazing me is that - somehow - Kolmogorov figured out a way to make it more formal, so it jumped from discrete combinatorics to continuous functions and values.

If we refer to the Probability Density Function as the pdf, and the Cumulative Distribution Function (surface) as the CDF, all of the following are true:

1. We can get the probability of an event as the integral to the right limits of the pdf; or
2. We can look up the probability directly from the point on the CDF surface. 
   So far, nothing fancy per se.

So, it can be seen that simply: we have a 3-D surface that ranges from $-\infty$ to $\infty$for both the X and Y axis.  And, we have floating above it a surface which has value zero at either end on the left/below: i.e., the value if either limit is $-\infty$ is zero.  And, as the point of interst in X-Y space moves positive, the function grows in  non-decreasing manner along the X or Y axis, ending up at one when both limits go to $\infty$.

It seems at times blindingly obvious but hard for me to put on a mathematical footing.  What is it about this definition that allows us to treat random variables algebraically, whil keeping in mind what it really is and applying some logic to it.

Put more crudely, why can I pretend an RV is just a variable, manipulate to my heart's content, then "apply the rules of probability" to the outcome?  How does the "probabilitiness" make this all hold together?

Comment: A "random variable"  is simply a function, of an appropriate type. Have a look at the concept of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue–Stieltjes_integration for context of the notion of "probability density function".

Comment: For reference, Kolmogorov put probability theory on a *measure theoretic* footing in his work *The Foundations of the Theory of Probability*, unifying both discrete RVs and continuous RVs into one theory, among many other nice things.

Comment: Yeah, I see that.  But the big insight was not so much unifying discrete and continuous as it is laying everything down right so one can abstract and use algebra on distributions successfully.  I think I'm looking for the "among many other nice things" I am curious about...what are they?

Comment: conditional expectation with respect to $\sigma$-algebras, the Daniel-Kolmogorov existence theorem are just two examples. But as far as doing algebraic operations on random variables or CDFs, that all immediately works once you define (real-valued) RVs as measurable real-valued functions of the sample space: $X:\Omega\to \mathbb{R}$. We can add $g(x)+f(x)$ for real functions and we can also add for each outcome $\omega \in \Omega$ two RVs on the same space $X(\omega) +Y(\omega)$, but this notation is usually suppressed until emphasized, see e.g. D. Williams *Probability with Martingales*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're asking a more general question like "why do mathematical models work?", which is arguably more philosophical than mathematical.

For probability theory, you could describe what's going on as:

1. We have intuitions about "real-life randomness" and its properties, constituting informal "rules of probability".
2. We invent a way of modeling real-life randomness using precisely-defined mathematical objects ([probability spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_space), [random variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable), distribution functions, etc.). We carefully formulate our definitions to codify the basic facts that characterize real-world randomness. This includes formalizing the [rules of probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_axioms) as precise axioms.
3. Once we've defined random variables as abstract mathematical objects, we can study them using any tools we want (calculus, algebra, geometry, etc.). **These tools are just different ways of finding logical consequences of our formal definitions.** Because we trust our foundational [systems of mathematical deduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foundations_of_mathematics), we know that anything we prove follows logically from our assumptions.
4. We can interpret formal theorems about random variables as useful facts about real-world randomness.

If you find it surprising that that this process works so well, you might be interested in [this discussion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Unreasonable_Effectiveness_of_Mathematics_in_the_Natural_Sciences).

Comment: I see what you're saying. The issue is less seeing it work than imagining how anyone could ever figure out how to glue it all together.  Measure theory is deep in their, but your points #2 and #3 get a bit closer to the answer to my question.  Could you give a formal example of some other "mathematical objects" not having to do with probability or measure?